# How do I ensure a systemd service runs before SSH server closes?

Tags: systemd

I have made a `systemd` service which performs some actions just before the machine shuts down. Its unit file is:

```
[Unit]
Before=shutdown.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/demo.sh
TimeoutSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target
```

Currently, the script runs before the machine loses network connection, but after SSH connections are closed, and if I try to reconnect, it fails with “Connection refused” error. I would prefer keeping SSH connection until the script itself terminates (for instance to be able to `tail -f /var/log/syslog` its execution.)

How do I force to run the script before SSH server closes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve required result by using a systemd unit as below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to run on shutdown before any other services
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/opt/demo.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutStopSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

systemd stop's services based on their dependency in reverse order. So above service starts `/bin/true` after system reached `default.target` and your script `/opt/demo.sh` on stop/shutdown. Based on your requirement, you would want to tweak `TimeoutStopSec`, currently it's set to never timeout (instead of default 90 sec)